# Insecure connections are not allowed in android emulator device for localhost

Tags: android, ios, android-emulator, appium

I am facing an issue while i am trying to use http://localhost:8080 to login in android emulator. It is working for ios device. Is there any way for force it to accept http request? I have checked few stackoverflow answer where they have mentioned to add manula proxy using ip and port but nothing is working.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        
        ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you mean i have to edit apk. Right? Because I have apk only .

Comment: @DSV Yes, from Android 9, cleartext traffics are disabled by default. And when you are using AVD, to connnect to localhost, you might need to use 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: Oh, okay. Let me check any tool i can use to edit it.

Comment: i tried with 10.0.2.2 but still i got insecure error. Checking if I can edit the xml.

Comment: @DSV Because editing the manifest file can lead to security issues, I think it is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, got the new apk. It is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this config on your Appium server:

```
Remote host: localhost
Remote port: 4723
Remote path: /wd/hub
```

> http://localhost:4723

Appium command to running:

```
appium --allow-cors
```

Comment: Thanks but it is different issue. My issue got resolved with a new apk.

Comment: It's ok, that's good case for change with new APK file.